# How come paragraphs don't work in FLEXBOX?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, line-breaks, paragraph

I have this very basic HTML code with some centered flex content inside a full-screen div. However when I preview it, none of the paragraphs create a new paragraph. Instead, they all appear on a single line. Did I do something wrong?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<style>
.main {
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main">
        <p>first line</p>
        <p>second line</p>
        <p>third line</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: change flex direction

Comment: Generally you don't want to give `display: flex` to a container for written content (headings, paragraphs, etc.) But what are you actually trying to achieve here?

Comment: flex-direction:column; is what you're looking for, add it to the .main

Comment: @AbdullahAlNoor not sure I understand. Could you be more specific? Which flex-direction should I use?

Comment: flex has two direction x axis and y axis.. default x-axis ..

Comment: default   `flex-direction: row;`  x-axis.. another  `flex-direction: column;` y-axis

Comment: @LionelRowe what I'm actually trying to do is create a full-screen footer at the bottom of my page and insert three lines of text into the very center of the full-screen footer. Some recommended I use flexbox for that.

Comment: You can use a container div for the content, then wrap that div in the flex footer. So your structure would be `footer.flex>div>p*3`

Comment: Thank you @LionelRowe. Do you mind showing me the final code? I'm such a noob.

Comment: plz check [link](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_flexbox_justify-content_center)

Comment: Unfortunately I can't write an answer because this has been closed as a duplicate of an unrelated question. But here's a jsbin: https://jsbin.com/xuhayic/edit

Comment: Thank you @AbdullahAlNoor for the code.

Comment: Thank you @LionelRowe for the code.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your replies. Appreciate it.